# Open activity without disappearing bottom bar

Tags: android

According to new Bottom Bar solution, I can't find idea for achieving something like this:

[Gif with new Activity](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)

I understand that after click on image new Activity is opening, but how it's possible to open it without disappearing Bottom Bar ?

**EDIT**

I'm talking about example where in Music tab user is clicking on Kodaline album and than it reveals something like new activity.

Comment: By using Fragments I think, instead of Activity and keep the "Bottom Bar" on the parent activity layout. [This example](http://blog.grafixartist.com/bottom-navigation-bar-android-tutorial/) should give you the clue.

Answer (score 1):

A new activity is not being launched or else the bottom nav bar would disappear for a split second. The basic idea is to have an activity that inflates views or fragments into a container based on which item is selected. I'd recommend using views over fragments because certain FragmentTransaction bugs are especially hard to track down and you are at the mercy of FragmentManager while you have full control defining custom views. The sample gif sets the visibility of the bottom nav to View.GONE and animates away the bottom nav during the scroll.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
YourBottomNavView.OnItemClickListener {

    ViewGroup viewContainer;
    YourBottomNavView bottomNav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewContainer = findViewById(R.id.view_container);
        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
        bottomNav.setItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int item) {
        viewContainer.removeAllViews();
        View nextView = getView(item);
        viewContainer.addView(nextView);
    }

    private View getView(int item) {
        //Insert logic
    }
}
```

**R.layout.activity_main**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"/>

    <YourBottomNavView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Alternatively, you can use fragments to inject into your viewContainer, but I find using plain old views much more reliable than the random bugs fragments may throw at you.

Here is an example of a custom view

```
public class YourAwesomeView extends LinearLayout {

    public YourAwesomeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public YourAwesomeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.YOUR_AWESOME_VIEW, this);
    }
}
```

**YourBottomNavView.java**

```
public class YourBottomNavView extends LinearLayout {
    View button1, button2, button3;
    View root;
    OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public YourBottomNavView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public YourBottomNavView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_bottom_nav, this);
        root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1_container);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2_container);
        button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3_container);

        //The button clicks need to communicate to something like the
        //activity to inflate your new view / fragment. I personally
        //define an OnItemClickedListener interface in the 
        //YourBottomNavView class that the MainActivity implements
        //and I have the activity decide which view to inflate into
        //its frame layout. This is also where you can do cool
        //animations like we saw from the GIFs.
        //This is also where you can swap out drawables to color the  
        //ImageViews differently.

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(0);
                root.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0000);
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(1);
                root.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(2);
                root.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(int item);
    }
}
```

**R.layout.view_bottom_nav**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@color/default_color"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button1_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weight="1">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            src="@drawable/icon1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button2_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weight="1">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            src="@drawable/icon1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button3_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weight="1">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            src="@drawable/icon3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: IMO the first solution proposed is terrible, as the code gets confusing. I'd rather go with option #2, use some kind of Host Activity that holds the navBarView and change fragments inside of it, it's simpler, cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: But how it's possible that color of status bar is changing ? It should require reloading activity or creating new one

Comment: I've done this using fragments before and if you are more comfortable with them it will be a similar solution where you inflate the fragment into the FrameLayout. As I stated, however, I've ran into some FragmentTransaction bugs that were impossible to debug. For your onClickListeners for the bottom nav you would have to manage the states yourself. So when you click a button you need to make sure the others are set to "unselected" while the one you clicked is "selected" and change colors accordingly.

Comment: You don't understand. I'm talking about example where in Music tab user is clicking on Kodaline album and than it reveals something like new activity.

Comment: It's not a new activity. If it were a new activity the whole screen would have to be redrawn and the bottom nav would disappear for a second. When the user taps the Kodaline album a new view is animated and is inflated into the container. I have a friend at Google who favors plain old Views versus Fragments. I'm simply conveying to you that to accomplish this you need to inflate a View or Fragment into a container.

Comment: When one of the icons are clicked, there is an API from the ImageView where you can change assets http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int). This is one way to accomplish it and just happens to be the way i chose when I implemented my own bottom navigation. For your bottom nav view you can also change the background color for the container of your bottom nav icons.

Comment: So you are saying that under status bar is just image ? And do you know how to add view on another that it has back button on the top left ? Can you share some code ?

Comment: Sure I'll update my answer with a sample BottomNav implememtation.

Comment: I'm afraid you are not right. Cause how is it possible in your example when we click on Kodaline album and new view is opening, and then we want to click back button in top left. For example recycler view in first view was scrolled to center, and we want after clicking back button to be in the same moment in recycler view and in your example it would refresh all the view.

Answer (score 0):

After several months thinking about this problem for my app.
I found that its very difficult to achieve the desired behavior with only the MVC pattern used in Android apps, because keeping your Main Activity on screen along app flow would overload this class.

Although Google Android tutorials spread this MVC idea, the real Google apps and design examples (like this beautiful music player you said) are far ahead in terms of architecture and code organization.

The real solution to this problem is to uncouple the logic and the views using another pattern than MVC. You may want to read about patterns used in [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) in order to have your heavy code uncoupled in several classes and still keeping the same Activity (that one with the bottom bar) on screen.